# Kdenlive has no menu buttons like File, Edit (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - XFCE)

Tags: 20.04, kde, xfce, kdenlive

For some reason kdenlive, appimage or PPA doesn't let me see the menu buttons(File, Edit, etc.)
Ctrl + M doesn't work and neither does going into the config files and enabling them(after closing it it sets them back to Disabled?) I should of got any kde dependency's I needed after getting the PPA so I'm not sure what the issue is, any help?

[Kdenlive with no menu buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI8rP.png)

Comment: If you right-click in the toolbar, just to the right of *Render* and select Toolbar Settings > Text Position and then select  Text Under Icons, does that fix your issue? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this didn't seem to change anything. Thanks

Comment: I have this problem as well. No Menu bar for Kdenlive, CTRL M does not do anything. Ubuntu 20.04 , Unity is my X - do I have to be using KDE?

Comment: @NicoleCook Please start your own new question.

Answer (score 2):

"Ctrl+M" solved the problem